# make a returned JSON boolean value check a checkbox in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Using autocomplete I'm getting data that's being returned with JSON data ....

### Here's the JSON data thats returning from the QUERY.

```
 [{"value":"Company Test 1 Manager Test 1 111-111-1111","Company_Name":"Company Test 1","Manager":"Manager Test 1","Phone":"111-111-1111","Contacted":"1"},
 {"value":"Company Test 2 Manager Test 2 222-222-2222","Company_Name":"Company Test 2","Manager":"Manager Test 2","Phone":"222-222-2222","Contacted":"0"},
 {"value":"Company Test 3 Manager Test 3 333-333-3333","Company_Name":"Company Test 3","Manager":"Manager Test 3","Phone":"333-333-3333","Contacted":"0"},
 {"value":"Company Test 4 Manager Test 4 444-444-4444","Company_Name":"Company Test 4","Manager":"Manager Test 4","Phone":"444-444-4444","Contacted":"1"},
 {"value":"Company Test 5 Manager Test 5 555-555-5555","Company_Name":"Company Test 5","Manager":"Manager Test 5","Phone":"555-555-5555","Contacted":"0"},]
```

## Now, here's my JQuery (using JQuery 1.6.2)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#Company_Name').val("");
    $('#Manager').val("");
    $('#Phone').val("");
    $('#Contacted').val("");

           $("#autoSearch").autocomplete({
                source: "UPDATE.test001QUERY.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#Company_Name').val(ui.item.Company_Name);
                        $('#Manager').val(ui.item.Manager);
                        $('#Phone').val(ui.item.Phone);

                    if ('#Contacted' == [1]) {
                            $('#Contected').prop('checked', true);
                            } else {
                            $('#Contected').prop('checked', false);
                            }

                }
            });
     }); 
</script>
```

What did I do wrong? The autocomplete works fine but the checkbox does not "check" based on the "0" or "1" thats returned from the QUERY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

`if ('#Contacted' == [1])`

should be

`if (ui.item.Contacted === "1")`

Edit,

the first thing you need to do is determine if the `if` statement in your `select` callback is being entered under the correct circumstances.

if it is, you need to figure out why you are not modifying the right dom.  So I see your selector is `#Contected`.  Are you sure you have a checkbox with an `id` attribute `Contected`?  Should it be `Contacted`?

Comment: Nope, didn't change anything. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @monty updated answer with some more hints; without seeing the html its hard to know

Comment: Wow, I'm embarrassed now. Yeah, typo I'll go get some glasses THANKS!

Comment: sometimes you just need another pair of eyes on it.  Typos happen all the time.